# Images and plugins fail to load when mvc-3 application is published to Windows Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, azure

When we publish mvc-3 project to windos azure, Is it copy all files and folder under the project name folder, means likes Scripts, Contents, etc ?. I am asking this because i just publish my mvc-3 application to windowsazure and after that when i run it using staging url then it not shown the images, plugin are stop working and when i inspect under chrome then it shows :

[image]
[image]

If you notice than there are few Scripts ( `like sammy.js` ) and stylesheets ( `like Site.css` ) which are present but maximums are not. Can please anybody explain me how can i fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Ok , i found out the root cause, this is happening because each time when i was downloaded the new plugin

i just copy the .`js`  from its source folder and then paste it into my project's `Scripts` folder. But only after

putting the file inside the Scripts folder does not includes it in the project. You can`t see that file in the

solution explorer until you explicitly include it in the project.There is a button in the solution explorer on the top

of it for show all file, included the files which are not the part of the project.Then Just `right click` on the

file which you want to included in the project and select option `Include in the project`. Then only that

file becomes the part of your project. Now you can publish the project and everything will works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure they are included in the .csproj file
Make sure they are marked as Build Action: Content

Comment: I did the same thing a couple weeks ago with the less files for Twitter Bootstrap. :)